# Extracting .currentCellRow fields from SAP to Excel

Tags: excel, vba, sap-gui

I have been using vba with SAP for a while now and have never run into this particular issue.

Usually, when script recording in SAP, I click on a field and am left with some string of code with a .setfocus as the end. I replace this with .text in order to extract the data in that cell.

I have run into a menu that ends in .currentCellRow= # and thus if I change it, it loses its position and has no idea what field I am talking about.

Is there any way that I can adjust this to pull data from these fields?

Here is an example of a field I scripted

```
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlGRID1/shellcont/shell").currentCellRow = 4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.getcellvalue(4,"name of column")

see too: https://answers.sap.com/questions/300278/reading-grid-cells-sap-gui-scripting-vbs.html

Regards,
ScriptMan