# Extracting Data From SAP Into Excel .currentcellrow

Tags: vba, sapui5

I am trying to pull data from SAP into Excel from a list inside SAP. Normally when I click a field, I get a string of code with either .setfocus or something similar that I can change to a .text and set the line equal to a variable.

When I click a field in this list I get something like this

```
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlCUSTOM/shellcont/shell").currentCellRow = 2
```

What I need it to be able to make this variable to loop through, and in every iteration assign the SAP Cell value to a variable.

Does anyone know what I can do to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Okay I have no memory of asking this question in the past, but I apparently did. Here is the link to the answer from before.

[Extracting .currentCellRow fields from SAP to Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52010710/extracting-currentcellrow-fields-from-sap-to-excel)

Admins: Feel free to remove this post since it is a duplicate. Sorry for the inconvenience!